# Need to read huge excel file with 60 column in java using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am reading excel file with around 60 column and 500 rows. I am converting them in our java object form using Apahce POI. But all this I am doing it with switch statement and making different case based on column index. I don't think it is correct way to iterate excel and convert it to java objects. So can you suggest me nice way to do this.

Currently doing like this....

```
public class Employee
{
private String empNo;
private String empName;
...
..
...
....like this 60 column header 
...
}
```

I don't like it to do this way, is there any other way you can suggest me. 
Thanks for help in advance
in another class.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
List<Employee> list = new AraayList<Employee>();
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        switch(cell.getColumnIndex()) {
            case 0:
                e.setEmpName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case 1:
                e.setEmpNo(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
                .....
                ......
                ......
                ..
                ...
            case 60: e.setStreet(cell.getStringCellValue());
                list.add(e);
                break;
        }
    }
}

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a POJO, then I don't think there is a better way to do this, except for transferring the setter code inside the POJO.

```
public class Employee{
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    // ... 60 such fields

    public getFieldA(){
         return fieldA;
    }
    // ...60 such getters(and setters);

    public void setField(int index,String value){
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                fieldA=value;
            // ...60 such cases
        }
    }
}
```

And in the driver class, you could use it by just writing:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
    Employee emp=new Employee();
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++){
        emp.setField(i,cell.row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```